# Python execvp error

Tags: python

I wrote the following two pieces of code:

The first one is called_Process.py

```
print("Hello Python!!")
closeInput = raw_input("Press Enter to exit")
print "Closing calledProcess"
```

The second program is calling_Process.py which calls the above program:

```
import os
import sys

program = "python"
print("Process Calling")
arguments = ["called_Process.py"]
os.execvp(program, (program,) + tuple(arguments))
print("Finished calling called_Process!!")
```

When I run calling_Process.py on Windows using python 3.6.0, I get the following error:

```
Process Calling
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ND/Desktop/calling_Process.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.execvp(program, (program,) + tuple(arguments))
  File "C:\Users\ND\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 623, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "C:\Users\ND\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 668, in _execvpe
    raise last_exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\ND\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 658, in _execvpe
    exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>> os.environ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    os.environ()
TypeError: '_Environ' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me understand what is causing this error?

Comment: What is up with your args parameter

Comment: Are you sure that your `python` is in your `PATH`?  If not, that would explain it quite trivially.

Comment: And have a look at `os.environ`, not at `os.environ()`.  The former is a dictionary which you cannot call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Adding the path did fix it. Appreciate the prompt response.